# Drag-n-drop emails to a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

**Problem Statement:** There is a Document Library named "Temp". This library is associated with a content type "Cnt_Temp" which contains the DropDownList for the field document type Legal Document, Preview Document, Art Document, Presentation document etc. Now I open a library in Explorer View and drop an Outlook 2007 email (sample email) into this library. When I drop the email it should generate a pop up or something where the user can mention the type of document from the drop down list, which is a field in the content type.

**WSS limitation:** Content type selection box is not invoked when performing drag-n-drop or copy-paste functionality.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the solution you want does not exist.

You could add minor and major versioning to the document library, requiring the users to check in the document before it is published. This will bring up a property window.

You could create a custom event handler that would add metadata based on the content type (e.g. ".msg"), but I doubt that would be a useful solution.